# Add number to NSNumber

Tags: ios, math, nsnumber

I want to + and - some values to the current longitude:

```
NSNumber *Latitude = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble:location.latitude];
NSNumber *Longitude = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble:location.longitude];

NSLog(@"Numbers:%@ %@", Latitude, Longitude);

2012-11-19 08:31:52.740 SR Navigatie[16748:907] Numbers:52.17401375095112 4.98983223979254
```

I want to make NSString or an NSNumber to LatMin, LatMax, LonMin, LonMax.

So to Latmin i want to - 0.005, 
LatMax +0.005,
LonMin -0.005,
LonMax +0.005.

Does anyone know how to do this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't it this simple?

```
NSNumber *latMin  = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble:location.latitude -0.005];
NSNumber *latMax = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble:location.latitude +0.005];
NSNumber *lonMin = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble:location.longitude -0.005];
NSNumber *lonMax = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble:location.longitude +0.005];
```

Comment: @Babboe Thats happened to me before! I call it 'coders block'!

Comment: But do you also know how to convert this to a nsstring

Comment: NSString *latMinString = [latMin stringValue];